# pandas groupby replace based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset structures as below:

```
index country  city     Data
0     AU       Sydney   23
1     AU       Sydney   45
2     AU       Unknown  2
3     CA       Toronto  56
4     CA       Toronto  2
5     CA       Ottawa   1
6     CA       Unknown  2
```

I want to replace 'Unknown' in the city column with the mode of the occurences of cities per country. The result would be:

```
...
2     AU       Sydney  2
...
6     CA       Toronto  2
```

I can get the city modes with:

```
city_modes = df.groupby('country')['city'].apply(lambda x: x.mode().iloc[0])
```

And I can replace values with:

```
df['column']=df.column.replace('Unknown', 'something')
```

But i cant work out how to combine these to only replace unknowns for each country based on mode of occurrence of cities.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `Series` with same size as original `DataFrame` and set new values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
city_modes = df.groupby('country')['city'].transform(lambda x: x.mode().iloc[0])
df['column'] = np.where(df['column'] == 'Unknown',city_modes, df['column'])
```

Or:

```
df.loc[df['column'] == 'Unknown', 'column'] = city_modes
```